# select the second row from the html table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I use the following jquery function for highlight the row ( using bg color ) in Html table.It was working fine.my question is how to select the second row from the table.'highlight' is a class

```
.highlight td {
  background: #E7EFFA;
}

$('#Tabnameabcd tr').mouseover(function() {
  if ($.trim($(this).text()) != '')
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
}).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('highlight');
});

which means:

name    age    depart

test    12     test
test1   13     tested
```

here **name,age,depart** as a first row.that is title.
next **test,test1** are elements of the tabe.if i use that jquery function the title( name,age,depart ) are apply.**i need to apply that jquery function only to the elements of the table not a title**?how to do this?

Comment: Put the header rows in a thead element, put the id on a tbody element. Instead of a listener on every single row, consider a single listener on the tbody that uses `event.target` to get the row, then goes from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get second row: `$('#Tabnameabcd tr').eq(1)` or `$('#Tabnameabcd tr:eq(1)')`.

To get all rows from second one (Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pXj5F/):

```
$('#Tabnameabcd :nth-child(n+2)')
```

Also you should think about `thead` and `tbody`...

Comment: it was not working for me..if i use like this i didn't get the class to apply from second row..

Comment: <table><tr><td>name</td><td>age</td><td>depart</td></tr></table> and i enter the element in this same structure.Am not using <th></th>

Comment: @ Speransky Danil if i use like this $('#Tabnameabcd :nth-child(n+2)').the whole table will get highlight on mouseover.due to some reasons am not using th ele,ents

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16857/discussion-between-user-and-speransky-danil)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$('#mytable_id tr').eq(1).(your function here);
```

and you want to apply for the rows not the tiltes then you can also use

```
$("#mytable_id td").function({
      //Play here
});
```

it will applicable to all the td's of your table excluding titles.you can also use ".not()" function instaed of this